# How do I disable the default input source in macOS Sonoma?

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout

I have long been using a custom keyboard layout which contains all the regular and special characters that I need for my work.

I have a new Mac using macOS Sonoma, and I've installed the custom keyboard layout as usual.

However, whenever I select the custom input source in preferences to the built-in British input source, the system defaults to British instantly.

In the past I managed to remove the British input source, leaving only the custom one, but I cannot see how to do that in macOS Sonoma.